# How can I syntax highlight go template files in Atom?

Tags: html, go, atom-editor, hugo

I have a bunch of `.html` files that I'm working on that are really golang template files. If I rename the files to `.gohtml` then Atom correctly highlights the gaoling template tokens as well as the HTML. I can't rename the files to `.gohtml` (they must remain `.html`) as I am using the [Hugo static site generator](https://gohugo.io) that fails if you do.

Is there a way to make Atom highlight all `.html` files as if they were `.gohtml` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the grammar of the file manually. And Atom remembers your choice when you open this file again.

But if you want to map a filetype to a new language there is a plugin [file-types](https://atom.io/packages/file-types).

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same challenge, I found two possibilities:

- For partial templates, rename the `template.html` to `template.gohtml`. I did a quick check and this worked fine for me if it is called as `{{ partial "template.gohtml" . }}` (hugo v0.36, linux).
- [Configure Atom directly](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#customizing-language-recognition):

  1. Open the Atom Settings page and click "Open Config Folder"
  2. Open `config.cson`
  3. Add the language config in the `core`-section:

     ```
     "*":
       core:
         customFileTypes:
           "text.html.gohtml": [
             "html"
           ]
     ```